# Could not convert variante of type (OleStr) into type (Double)

Tags: delphi

Quero fazer um laço de repetição onde a cada loop ele seta o nome da pessoa mais a variável, porem quando eu junto a variável do tipo integer com um texto da uma mensagem de erro falando "Could not convert variant of type (OleStr) into type (Double).

Alguém já passou por isso e pode me dar uma luz.

```
procedure CadastrarPessoa;
var
Contador, n1: integer;

begin
n1:= 1;

for Contador:= 0 to 9 do  
begin
CadastraPessoa.AbrirCadastraPessoa;

CadastraPessoa.BtnNovo;
CadastraPessoa.InformaNome('Morador Modelo ' + n1);
CadastraPessoa.CheckEnderecoCondominio;
CadastraPessoa.InformaTelefone('(37) 3222-2244');
CadastraPessoa.InformaCelular('(37) 98877-6699');
CadastraPessoa.InformarEmail('morador' + n1 + '@teste.com');
CadastraPessoa.FinalizaCadastro;

CadastraPessoa.BtnGravar;
CadastraPessoa.BtnSair;
n1:= n1 + 1;
end;
end;
```

Caso eu defina somente uma string funciona ou se eu definir somente um numero ele funciona também agora quando eu junto esses dois da o erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça a conversão do Inteiro para Texto que irá funcionar:

```
CadastraPessoa.InformarEmail('morador' + IntToStr(n1) + '@teste.com');
```

Em Delphi para concatenar uma `String` com outro tipo é necessário realizar conversões, por exemplo:

```
ValorTotal: Double -> 'Valor:'+ FloatToStr(ValorTotal);
Quantidade: Integer -> 'Tem '+ IntToStr(Quantidade) +' de maças na cesta';
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo aqui não acredito que esse era meu erro.

Comment: Por nada, só não esqueça de marcar alguma das respostas como "Aceita"!

Answer (score 1):

Você está tentando concatenar uma String com um inteiro. É preciso fazer a conversão
'Sua String ' + IntToStr(n1);

Comment: valeu obrigado.